# How to partially extract zipped huge plain text file?

Tags: text-processing, zip

I have a zip file with size of 1.5 GB.

Its content is one ridiculous large plain-text file (60 GB) and I currently do not have enough space on my disk left to extract it all nor do I want to extract it all, even if I had.

As for my use case, it would suffice if I can inspect parts of the content.

Hence I want to unzip the file as a stream and access a range of the file (like one can via head and tail on a normal text file).

Either by memory (e.g. extract max 100kb starting from 32GB mark) or by  lines (give me the plain text lines 3700-3900).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to seek on an individual file within a zip. So any soloution will involve reading through the file up to the point you are interested in.

Comment: @plugwash As I understand the question, the goal is not to avoid reading through the zip file (or even the decompressed file), but simply to avoid *storing* the entire decompressed file in memory or on disk. Basically, treat the decompressed file as a [stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note that `gzip` can extract `zip` files (at least the first entry in the `zip` file). So if there's only one huge file in that archive, you can do:

```
gunzip < file.zip | tail -n +3000 | head -n 20
```

To extract the 20 lines starting with the 3000th one for instance.

Or:

```
gunzip < file.zip | tail -c +3000 | head -c 20
```

For the same thing with bytes (assuming a `head` implementation that supports `-c`).

For any arbitrary member in the archive, in a Unixy way:

```
bsdtar xOf file.zip file-to-extract | tail... | head...
```

With the `head` builtin of `ksh93` (like when `/opt/ast/bin` is ahead in `$PATH`), you can also do:

```
.... | head     -s 2999      -c 20
.... | head --skip=2999 --bytes=20
```

Note that in any case `gzip`/`bsdtar`/`unzip` will always need to uncompress (and discard here) the entire section of the file that leads to the portion that you want to extract. That's down to how the compression algorithm works.

Comment: If `gzip` can handle it, will the other "z aware" utilities (`zcat`, `zless`, etc) also work?

Comment: @ivanivan, on systems where they're based on `gzip` (generally true of `zless`, not necessarily of `zcat` which on some systems is still to read `.Z` files only), yes.

Answer (score 13):

One solution using unzip -p and dd, for example to extract 10kb with 1000 blocs offset:

```
$ unzip -p my.zip | dd ibs=1024 count=10 skip=1000 > /tmp/out
```

Note: I didn't try this with really huge data...

Comment: In the general case of more than once file inside a single archive one can use `unzip -l ARCHIVE` to list the archive content and `unzip -p ARCHIVE PATH` to extract the content of a single object `PATH` to stdout.

Comment: Generally, using `dd` on pipes with count or skip is unreliable as it will do that many `read()`s of **up to** 1024 bytes. So it's only guaranteed to work properly if `unzip` writes to the pipe in chunks whose size is a  multiple of 1024.

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the creation of that big zip file, why not consider using a combination of `gzip` and `zless`?

This would allow you to use `zless` as a pager and view the contents of the file without having to bother with extraction.

If you cannot change the compression format then this would obviously not work. If so, I feel like `zless` is rather convenient.

Comment: I don't. I am downloading the zipped file provided by an external company.

Answer (score 3):

To view specific lines of the file, pipe the output to the Unix stream editor, [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).  This can process arbitrarily large streams of data, so you can even use it for changing the data.  To view lines 3700-3900 as you asked, run the following.

```
unzip -p file.zip | sed -n 3700,3900p
```

Comment: `sed -n 3700,3900p` will keep on reading until the end of the file. It's better to use `sed '3700,$!d;3900q'` to avoid that, or even generally more efficient: `tail -n +3700 | head -n 201`

Answer (score 3):

I wondered if it was possible to do anything more efficient than decompressing from the start of the file up to the point.  It appears that the answer is no.  However, on some CPUs (Skylake) `zcat | tail` doesn't ramp the CPU up to full clock speed.  See below.  A custom decoder could avoid that problem and save the pipe write system calls, and maybe be ~10% faster.  (Or ~60% faster on Skylake if you don't tweak power-management settings).

---

The best you could do with a customized zlib with a `skipbytes` function would be to parse the symbols in a compression block to get to the end without doing the work of actually reconstructing the decompressed block.  This could be significantly faster (probably at least 2x) than calling zlib's regular decode function to overwrite the same buffer and move forward in the file.  But I don't know if anyone's written such a function.  (And I think this doesn't actually work unless the file was written specially to allow the decoder to restart at a certain block).

I was hoping there was a way to skip through Deflate blocks without decoding them, because that would be *much* faster.  The Huffman tree is sent at the start of each block, so you can decode from the start of any block (I think).  Oh, I think the decoder state is more than the Huffman tree, it's also the previous 32kiB of decoded data, and this isn't reset / forgotten across block boundaries by default.  The same bytes can keep being referenced repeatedly, so might only appear literally once in a giant compressed file.  (e.g. in a log file, the hostname probably stays "hot" in the compression dictionary the whole time, and every instance of it references the previous one, not the first one).

[The `zlib` manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) says you have to use `Z_FULL_FLUSH` when calling `deflate` if you want the compressed stream to be seekable to that point. 
 It "resets the compression state", so I think without that, backwards references can go into the previous block(s).  So unless your zip file was written with occasional full-flush blocks (like every 1G or something would have negligible impact on compression), I think you would have to do more of the work of decoding up to the point you want than I was initially thinking.  I guess you probably can't start at the start of any block.

---

The rest of this was written while I was thinking it would be possible to just find the start of the block containing the first byte you want, and decode from there.

**But unfortunately, the start of a Deflate block doesn't indicate how long it is**, for compressed blocks.  Incompressible data can be coded with an uncompressed block type that has a 16-bit size in bytes at the front, but compressed blocks don't: [RFC 1951 describes the format pretty readably](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/RFC-1951).  Blocks with dynamic Huffman coding have the tree at the front of the block (so the decompressor doesn't have to seek in the stream), so the compressor has to have kept the whole (compressed) block in memory before writing it.

The maximum backwards-reference distance is only 32kiB, so the compressor doesn't need to keep much uncompressed data in memory, but that doesn't limit the block size.  Blocks can be multiple megabytes long.  (This is large enough for disk seek to be worth it even on a magnetic drive, vs. sequential read into memory and just skipping data in RAM, if it was possible to find the end of the current block without parsing through it).

zlib makes blocks as long as possible:
 [According to Marc Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176508/how-does-deflatezlib-determine-block-size), zlib only starts a new block when the symbol buffer fills up, which with the default setting is 16,383 symbols (literals or matches)

---

I gzipped the output of `seq` (which is extremely redundant and thus probably not a great test), but `pv < /tmp/seq1G.gz | gzip -d | tail -c $((1024*1024*1000)) | wc -c` on that runs at only ~62 MiB/s of compressed data on a Skylake i7-6700k at 3.9GHz, with DDR4-2666 RAM.  That's 246MiB/s of decompressed data, which is chump change compared to `memcpy` speed of ~12 GiB/s for block sizes too large to fit in cache.

(With `energy_performance_preference` set to the default `balance_power` instead of `balance_performance`, Skylake's internal CPU governor decides to only run at 2.7GHz, ~43 MiB /s of compressed data.  I use `sudo sh -c 'for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy[0-9]*/energy_performance_preference;do echo balance_performance > "$i";done'` to tweak it.  Probably such frequent system calls don't look like real CPU-bound work to the power-management unit.)

TL:DR: **`zcat | tail -c` is CPU bound even on a fast CPU, unless you have *very* slow disks.**  gzip used 100% of the CPU it ran on (and ran 1.81 instructions per clock, according to `perf`), and `tail` used 0.162 of the CPU it ran on (0.58 IPC).  The system was otherwise mostly idle.

I'm using Linux 4.14.11-1-ARCH, which [has KPTI enabled by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992137/how-to-check-that-kpti-is-enabled-on-my-ubuntu) to work around Meltdown, so all those `write` system calls in `gzip` are more expensive than they used to be :/

---

**Having the seek built-in to `unzip` or `zcat` (but still using the regular `zlib` decode function)** would save all those pipe writes, and would get Skylake CPUs to run at full clock speed.  (This downclocking for some kinds of load is unique to Intel Skylake and later, which have offload the CPU frequency decision making from the OS, because they have more data about what the CPU is doing, and can ramp up / down faster.  This is normally good, but here leads to Skylake not ramping up to full speed with a more conservative governor setting).

No system calls, just rewriting a buffer that fits in L2 cache until you reach the starting byte position you want, would probably make a few % difference at least.  Maybe even 10%, but I'm just making up numbers here.  I haven't profiled `zlib` in any detail to see how big a cache footprint it has, and how much the TLB flush (and thus uop-cache flush) on every system call hurts with KPTI enabled.

---

**There are a few software projects which do add a seek index to the gzip file format**.  This doesn't help you if you can't get anyone to generate seekable compressed files for you, but other future readers may benefit.

Presumably neither of these projects have a decode function that knows how to skip through a Deflate stream without an index, because they're only designed to work when an index *is* available.

- [GZinga: Seekable and Splittable Gzip](https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/blogs/tech/gzinga-seekable-and-splittable-gzip/).  Allows large block sizes.
- [BGZF - Blocked, Bigger & Better GZIP!](https://blastedbio.blogspot.ca/2011/11/bgzf-blocked-bigger-better-gzip.html) (small max block size = 64kiB hurts compression ratios a bit.  Designed for use with bioinformatics data, like FASTA, that are often used uncompressed, with transparent support in some python libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the zip file in a python session, using `zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r', allowZip64=True)` and once opened you can open, for read, any file inside the zip archive and read lines, etc., from it as if it were a normal file.