# Extract first 1000 lines of zip file

Tags: text-processing, zip, macos

Using `unzip` I'm attempting to extract the first 1000 lines from an xml file. From reading [How to partially extract zipped huge plain text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415799/how-to-partially-extract-zipped-huge-plain-text-file) I've used the answers to create:

```
unzip -p my_feed.zip | dd count=1000 > out.txt
```

which is close to what I'm trying to achieve.

```
man dd
```

describes :

```
count=n  Copy only n input blocks.
```

What is the size of an input block ? How to extract the first 1000 lines instead of first 1000 input blocks ?

Update:

I forgot to mention I'm using osx. I thought this would achieve same result:

```
gunzip < my_feed.zip | head -n 1000
```

but returns error:

```
gunzip: unknown compression format
```

Comment: @roaima please see update.

Comment: dd does not work with lines, only raw bytes. Please use `file my_feed.zip` and post the report it gives. GNU gunzip should work with zip files on Linux, but only if they contain a single file compressed with 'deflation' mode.

Comment: unzip will normally unpack files onto disk, so you can't pipe them into head. You might try unzip on one file to stdout: `unzip -c my_feed.zip desired_file | head -n 1000 > out1000.txt`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant why do need 'desired_file' ? unzip -c my_feed.zip | head -n 1000 > out1000.txt should suffice ?

Comment: zip files are archives -- they can contain multiple files. Using the -c or -p option outputs all the files to stdout. As you have not confirmed the actual type of my_feed.zip (as shown by `file`), or that there is a single file (as shown by `unzip -tv`), then I suggest you specify a single filename from the archive. gunzip should work with a single file, so I assume the file is either multi-file or corrupt. I note your OP used unzip with dd, and then gunzip with head, and wondered why you didn't try unzip with head anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
zcat myfile.zip | head -n 1000
```